# How to plot a geoplot on matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I would like to figure out how to plot a geoplot onto subplots in matplotlib. i.e. I have plotted a GeoDataFrame with geometries, and a column of counts, but I would like multiple maps on a grid of subplots

Also if you know a way to use facetgrid with geoplots, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoPandas plot is a single matplotlib axis, you can use it like any other plots. Plotting four maps in a grid of subplots could look like this.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
f, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), ncols=2, nrows=2)
world.plot(ax=axes[0][0], column='pop_est', cmap='Blues')
world.plot(ax=axes[0][1], column='gdp_md_est', cmap='Reds')
world.plot(ax=axes[1][0], column='continent')
world.plot(ax=axes[1][1])
```

[image: result]

If you want something more specific, you have to specify your question.